# javascript function to vertically center element

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to write a function to vertically center elements if they have a class called "vcenter(#)". For example, vcenter1 vcenter2. It's supposed to take the element's parent's innerheight and subtract the element's innerheight then divide by 2. The value then is applied to the css as the margin-top. It doesn't work though. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i=1; i<3; i++){
        var childID = $(".vcenter" + i);
        var parent = childID.parent().innerHeight();
        var child = childID.innerHeight();
        var marginTop = (parent - child)/2 + 'px';
        $(childID).css({"margin-top", marginTop})
    }
});
```

Comment: You're setting the value of variable "childID" to a string.  You then use it as if it were a jQuery object or something. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: yup, I'm kind of new to it, sorry!

Comment: So did you want `childID = $(".vcenter" + i);` ??

Comment: I just gave that a try, it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

How about this...
http://jsfiddle.net/mVn9S/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.vcenter').each(function () {
        var parent = $(this).parent().innerHeight();
        var child = $(this).innerHeight();

        $(this).css({
            'margin-top': ((parent - child) / 2) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

Have you considered using [CSS3 Flexbox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/) with a polyfill for old versions of IE?  Might be less work.

Comment: @user2540029 I recommend you substitute `$(this)` with `$this`, a variable that you create at the beginning of the each function.  Otherwise, those new `$(this)` creations pile up and affect your execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (i=1; i<3; i++){
        var childElement = $(".vcenter" + i);
        var parent = childElement.parent().innerHeight();
        var child = childElement.innerHeight();
        var marginTop = (parent - child) / 2;
        childElement.css({"margin-top": marginTop});
    }
});
```

Notice use of `;` at the end of lines - it's a good habit even in JS.

I don't know how your HTML looks but probably this could be easily generalized for all elements with `.vcenter` class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.vcenter').each(function() {
        var childElement = $(this);
        var parent = childElement.parent().innerHeight();
        var child = childElement.innerHeight();
        var marginTop = (parent - child) / 2;
        childElement.css({"margin-top": marginTop});
    });
});
```

Comment: hmmm just gave that a try but it doesn't work, thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Could you explain why it didn't work? Centered wrong, not centered at all? Error in console?

Comment: the function actually doesn't do anything

Comment: Check out an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HUr9z/1/ Notice the CSS styles and absolute positioning used.